# What is the solution of $\int \frac{a}{a^2+x^2}dx$?

Tags: integration

What is the solution of $\int \frac{a}{a^2+x^2}dx$?

I have tried: $\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}=\frac{\frac{1}{a}}{1+(x/a)^2}=\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{1+(x/a)^2}$ by multiplying both parts of the fraction by $a^{-2}$. Then the $(1/a)$ in front is a constant and the integral of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $\arctan{x}$. My answer should be: $\int \frac{a}{a^2+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{a} \arctan (x/a)$. BUT: Wolfram alpha showed me: $\int \frac{a}{a^2+x^2}dx=\arctan (x/a)$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: are you integration wrt x?

Comment: $$\int\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}=a\int\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}=a\int\frac1{a^2+x^2}=a\arctan \left(\frac xa\right)+C$$

Comment: Thanks, so now I know that my try was wrong. But what about wolfram alpha? You suggestions do not agree with wolfram alpha.

Comment: $$\int\frac{ada}{a^2+x^2}=\frac12\int\frac{2a}{a^2+x^2}=\frac12\ln|a^2+x^2|+C$$

Comment: The question is poorly stated as the independent variable is not defined.

Comment: But what about http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+a%2F%28a^2%2Bx^2%29+dx

Comment: @user50224 in WA$\int\frac aada=a+C$

Comment: Sorry, I the link does not work. You have got to copy everything after "about" into your browser.

Comment: As mentioned by Andre Nicolas, when you substitute $u=\frac{x}{a}$ you get that $du=\frac{1}{a}dx$, so you didn't take this into account when you found the antiderivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We start from your 
$$\int \frac{1}{a}\cdot \frac{1}{1+(x/a)^2}\,dx.$$
Let $u=\frac{x}{a}$. Then $du=\frac{1}{a}\,dx$, so $dx=a\,du$.
Our integral becomes
$$\int \frac{1}{a}\cdot \frac{1}{1+u^2}a\,du.$$
Note the cancellation of the $a$'s, and integrate. We get
$$\arctan(u)+C,\quad\text{which is}\quad \arctan(x/a)+C.$$

**Remarks:** $1.$ In the first iteration of the post, the $dx$ was left out. That may be the reason that there was an error in the substitution process.

$2.$ A somewhat cleaner way to do the substitution, without preliminary algebra, is to let $x=au$. Then $dx=a\,du$, and our integral is
$$\int\frac{a}{a^2+a^2u^2} a\,du.$$
Cancel the $a$'s, and we are finding $\int \frac{1}{1+u^2}\,du$.

Answer (score 3):

Setting $x=a\tan\theta,\dfrac xa=\tan\theta,\theta=\arctan\dfrac xa$

$$\int\frac1{1+(x/a)^2}dx=\int a\ d\theta=a\arctan(x/a)+K$$

Setting $a=1,$ we find $$\int\frac{dx}{1+(x)^2}=\arctan(x)+K$$

Observe the two $x$-s within **parentheses**

Comment: he didn't mentioned dx or da so this is wrong.

Comment: @Aditya, There is something called convention, right? He won't have set $x/a,$ had it been $da$

Comment: $$\int\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}=\frac12\int\frac{2a}{a^2+x^2}=\frac12\ln|a^2+x^2|+C$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Sorry what I meant was: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+a%2F%28a^2%2Bx^2%29+dx). Why is there no $a$ in front of arctan in wolfram alpha?

Comment: @user50224, Have you followed my answer?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee How did you get the following?: $\int \frac{a}{a^2+x^2}dx=\int\frac1{1+(x/a)^2}dx$?